# Can you build a camera obscura indoors, to watch a play upside-down as it's performed?

Tags: optics, theater

I've seen Youtube videos of people who have converted a room into a *camera obscura* to capture images of skyline/trees/clouds, but couldn't you capture indoor scenes too?  Or would you need bright outdoor light to penetrate the pinhole (considering that it is extra dark inside the camera obscura, the light entering the pinhole would need to be extra bright?)

And if it is possible, how large would the camera obscura have to be, how far away from the stage (or simply target area, wouldn't have to be a stage per se) to be able to see, something like a mime perform the trapped-in-the-box routine?

And what effects if any would lighting have?  Would, or should any lighting be placed behind or in front of the performer?

And finally, would the mime appear really tiny on the projected screen, or could you arrange it so it would at least appear life size?

Comment: You might try this on http://physics.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about photography and only very tangentially related.

Answer (score 2):

1. Your eyes are very sensitive once they become accustomed to the dark (rods can respond to single photons, although a higher flux is needed for actual image formation). You could probably see your mime on stage (under bright stage lights) dimly but intelligibly enough.
2. If you needed a brighter image you could use a lens instead of a pinhole without violating the 'camera obscura' definition (this improvement was added in the mid 1500's). Using a lens brings complications though, and the following is for the simpler case of using a pinhole.
3. The camera (room) part can be any size you want as long as it's obscura (dark). The image size varies with focal length (distance between pinhole and surface you're viewing the image on) and distance from the subject.
4. Lighting would have the usual effects as seen with or without a camera. Strong backlighting may accentuate flare and/or diffraction artifacts.
5. The mime can appear any size you want, depending on focal length and distance to subject. Generally, magnification= Li/Lo = Di/Do or the ratio of the subject size to the image size is equal to the ratio of focal length to the distance from the pinhole to the subject.

Example 1: if you want a 1:1 subject/image size, the distance from the pinhole to the viewing surface must equal the distance from the pinhole to the subject.

Example 2: For an image 1/10 the size of the subject your focal length would need to be 1/10 the distance from the front of the camera to the subject.